# canonical volume forms

Tags: manifolds

I have the following problem:
Find the canonical volume form of:
$$i) R_f(a,b):={(f(z)cos(\phi),f(z)sin(\phi),z)|(\phi,z)\in\mathbb{R}\times(a,b)}$$ with $f\in C^{\infty}((a,b))$ and $f>0$
$$ii)W:={(rcos(\phi),rsin(\phi),\phi)|(\phi,r)\in \mathbb{R^2}}$$
$$iii) {(u,v,h(u,v)|(u,v)\in\mathbb{R^2}}$$ with $h\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^2})$

We have the formula:
The canonical volume formula $\omega_{M|U}$ for a riemanian manifold and the map (U,x) is:
$$\omega_{M|U}=\sqrt{g}(dx^1\wedge,...,\wedge dx^n)$$
Let f(x,y) be a map of the manifold then $g_{ij}=<\partial xf,\partial yf>$. $g=det((g_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n)$

What exactly do I have to do? Do I have to find a map for each problem?
If I know the map I can determine the g. But how do I find these maps?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: I would ask you if you know $g$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$For uniformity of notation, let $(u, v) \mapsto \Phi(u, v)$ be a regular parametrized surface, and define the "components of the first fundamental form" to be the functions
$$
E = \Brak{\Phi_{u}, \Phi_{u}},\qquad
F = \Brak{\Phi_{u}, \Phi_{v}},\qquad
G = \Brak{\Phi_{v}, \Phi_{v}}.
$$
The canonical volume form (i.e., the area form of the parametrized surface) is
$$
\sqrt{EG - F^{2}}\, du \wedge dv.
$$

Comment: Do I have to use that on for example i): with Φ(ϕ,z)=f(z)cos(ϕ),f(z)sin(ϕ),z)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: So is the solution to i) is $g=(\partial_z f(z))^2*(f(z))^2$?

Comment: Not quite: If $(u, v) \leftrightarrow (z, \phi)$, then$$E = f'(z)^{2} + 1,\qquad F = 0,\qquad G = f(z)^{2},$$so $\sqrt{EG - F^{2}} = f(z) \sqrt{f'(z)^{2} + 1}$, and the volume form is this multiplied by $dz \wedge d\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. I just forgot to type the +1 in E.
Is the solution for ii) $$\sqrt{g}=\sqrt{r^2+1}$$ correct?

And the solution for iii) should be:
$$\sqrt{g}=\sqrt{(1+(\partial_uh(u,v))^2)*(1+(\partial_vh(u,v))^2)-(\partial_u\partial_vh^2(u,v))^2}=\sqrt{1+(\partial_uh(u,v))^2+(\partial_vh(u,v))^2}$$

Comment: Yes, those densities look good. (Again, though, the volume _form_ needs to be multiplied by $du \wedge dv$, or its equivalent depending on the names of the parameters.)

Comment: I know but I just wanted to check the $\sqrt{g}$. Thank you very much.